Device disconnects when BLE nordic device transmit data faster
The react native module sends a disconnect event on
BLE_GATT_STATUS_SUCCESS 0x0000
This generally happens when we send 3 data packets in 25ms. I am using PHY 2 and requestConnectionPriority too.
Expected behaviours:
It doesn't need to send the disconnect event on the device state changes to 0.
Version
react-native-ble-manager : 11.5.3
react-native: 0.73.4
System Information:
System:
  OS: Windows 10 10.0.19045
  CPU: (4) x64 Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-7200U CPU @ 2.50GHz
  Memory: 1.44 GB / 7.88 GB
Binaries:
  Node:
    version: 18.19.1
    path: C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.EXE
  Yarn: Not Found
  npm:
    version: 7.24.2
    path: C:\Program Files\nodejs\npm.CMD
  Watchman: Not Found
SDKs:
  Android SDK:
    API Levels:
      - "23"
      - "24"
      - "25"
      - "26"
      - "27"
      - "28"
      - "29"
      - "30"
      - "31"
      - "33"
      - "34"
    Build Tools:
      - 30.0.2
      - 30.0.3
      - 31.0.0
      - 33.0.0
      - 33.0.1
      - 34.0.0
    System Images:
      - android-31 | Google Play Intel x86 Atom_64
      - android-33 | Intel x86_64 Atom
      - android-34 | Google Play Intel x86_64 Atom
    Android NDK: Not Found
  Windows SDK:
    AllowAllTrustedApps: Disabled
    Versions:
      - 10.0.19041.0
IDEs:
  Android Studio: AI-231.9392.1.2311.11330709
  Visual Studio:
    - 17.1.32210.238 (Visual Studio Community 2022)
Languages:
  Java: 17.0.10
  Ruby: Not Found
npmPackages:
  "@react-native-community/cli": Not Found
  react:
    installed: 18.2.0
    wanted: 18.2.0
  react-native:
    installed: 0.73.4
    wanted: 0.73.4
  react-native-windows: Not Found
npmGlobalPackages:
  "*react-native*": Not Found
Android:
  hermesEnabled: true
  newArchEnabled: false
iOS:
  hermesEnabled: Not found
  newArchEnabled: Not found

